# gridpane javafx clickable cells that get toggled and untoggled

Tags: javafx, cell, gridpane, onmousedown

I am trying to create a gridpane that is toggled/untoggled as the user clicks on specific cells. For example, when the user clicks on a cell with the content "*", I would like the content of that specific cell to be changed into a blank cell " ". Similarly, if the user clicks on a cell with a blank content " ", I would like the content of that cell to be changed into a cell with the content "*".

Basically, I am starting out with a grid that is partly input as follows:

[image]

My gridpane is initially input as follows, I am keeping track of a matrix of booleans that represents whether there should be a "*" in one cell of the matrix. If there is a "*" in cell [i, j] of the gridpane, then the value of matrix[i,j] should be `true`, otherwise it should be `false`.

```
  boolean matrix[][] = new boolean[StateList.size()+1][RequirementList.size()+1];

    for( InstanceArtifact li: ListOfLinks) {
        int y=1; 
        for(InstanceArtifact re: RequirementList) {
            int x=1; 
            for(InstanceArtifact state: StateList) {
             if(li.getPropertyValue("linksource").equals(re) && li.getPropertyValue("linktarget").equals(state)) {

                     link= new Label("    *    "); 
                    //tick in cell (1,1)
                    grid.add(link, y, x); 
                    matrix[x][y]= true; 

                }
             else {
                   link= new Label("         "); 
                    //tick in cell (1,1)
                    grid.add(link, y, x); 

             }
             x++; 


        }
        y++; 
    }


    }




    }
```

What I would like to do is toggle/untoggle the stars, this is what I am trying to do with the code below, as we are clicking on a cell containing "*", meaning that `matrix[i][j]=true`, I am removing the corresponding label in the grid and I am adding a new label with an empty text. I also do the same thing in the opposite situation in which the label text is blank and I need to replace it with a label containing a star.

```
         grid.getChildren().forEach(element -> {
                         element.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        int matrixX= GridPane.getRowIndex(element); 
                        int matrixY= GridPane.getColumnIndex(element); 
                        if(element!=null  && matrixX!=0 && matrixY!=0) {

                             System.out.println("matrixX: "+matrixX+"   matrixY: "+matrixY);
                             System.out.println("matrixY: "+matrixY+" "+ matrix[matrixX][matrixY]);
                            if(matrix[matrixX][matrixY]==true && matrixX!=0 && matrixY!=0) {

                                   System.out.println("HEY I AM HERE FIRSTTTTTTTTT");

                                  Node newnode= new Label("     ");
                                  GridPane.clearConstraints(element); 
                                 // grid.getChildren().remove(element); 

                                grid.add(newnode, matrixY, matrixX); 
                                matrix[matrixX][matrixY]=false; 
                                /*for(int l=0; l<RequirementList.size(); l++) {
                                    for(int p=0; p<StateList.size(); p++) {
                                        System.out.println(l + "  "+p +" "+matrix[l][p]);
                                    }
                                }*/


                                //grid.add(mynode, matrixY+1, matrixX+1, 1, 1); 


                            }
                            else if(matrix[matrixX][matrixY]==false && matrixX!=0 && matrixY!=0){

                                 System.out.println("HEY I AM HERE SECONDDDDDDD   ");

                                /* for(int l=0; l<RequirementList.size(); l++) {
                                        for(int p=0; p<StateList.size(); p++) {
                                            System.out.println(l + "  "+p +" "+matrix[l][p]);
                                        }
                                    }*/

                                    Node falsenode= new Label("   *      ");
                                    GridPane.clearConstraints(element); 
                                     // grid.getChildren().remove(element); 

                                    grid.add(falsenode, matrixY, matrixX); 
                                    matrix[matrixX][matrixY]=true; 


                            }


                         //   System.out.println("Row: " + GridPane.getRowIndex(element));
                           // System.out.println("Column: " + GridPane.getColumnIndex(element));
                        }   
                        }

                });
                     });
```

My code is not behaving as expected, I would like the cell to be toggled/untoggled whenever the user clicks on a cell, the code is executed only the first time the user clicks on a given cell, if the user clicks on the same cell multiple times (more than once), then nothing happens.

Also, the line of code in which I am trying to remove a label is not working:

```
       grid.getChildren().remove(element);
```

Comment: Why not use a `ToggleButton` in each cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be better served with `ToggleButton`. Comments in code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class JavaFXApplication60 extends Application {   

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {     
        //Start create GUI
        Label lblRequirement11 = new Label("Requirement1");
        Label lblRequirement12 = new Label("Requirement2");
        Label lblRequirement13 = new Label("Requirement3");
        GridPane.setConstraints(lblRequirement11, 1, 0);
        GridPane.setConstraints(lblRequirement12, 2, 0);
        GridPane.setConstraints(lblRequirement13, 3, 0);

        Label lblState1 = new Label("State1");
        ToggleButton toggleButton11 = new ToggleButton();
        toggleButton11.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        ToggleButton toggleButton12 = new ToggleButton();
        toggleButton12.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        ToggleButton toggleButton13 = new ToggleButton();
        toggleButton13.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        GridPane.setConstraints(lblState1, 0, 1);
        GridPane.setConstraints(toggleButton11, 1, 1);
        GridPane.setConstraints(toggleButton12, 2, 1);
        GridPane.setConstraints(toggleButton13, 3, 1);

        Label lblState2 = new Label("State2");
        ToggleButton toggleButton21 = new ToggleButton();
        toggleButton21.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        ToggleButton toggleButton22 = new ToggleButton();
        toggleButton22.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        ToggleButton toggleButton23 = new ToggleButton();
        toggleButton23.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        GridPane.setConstraints(lblState2, 0, 2);
        GridPane.setConstraints(toggleButton21, 1, 2);
        GridPane.setConstraints(toggleButton22, 2, 2);
        GridPane.setConstraints(toggleButton23, 3, 2);

        Label lblState3 = new Label("State3");
        ToggleButton toggleButton31 = new ToggleButton();
        toggleButton31.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        ToggleButton toggleButton32 = new ToggleButton();
        toggleButton32.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        ToggleButton toggleButton33 = new ToggleButton();
        toggleButton33.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        GridPane.setConstraints(lblState3, 0, 3);
        GridPane.setConstraints(toggleButton31, 1, 3);
        GridPane.setConstraints(toggleButton32, 2, 3);
        GridPane.setConstraints(toggleButton33, 3, 3);

        GridPane root = new GridPane(); 
        root.setVgap(5);
        root.setHgap(5);
        root.getChildren().addAll(lblRequirement11, lblRequirement12, lblRequirement13);
        root.getChildren().addAll(lblState1, toggleButton11, toggleButton12, toggleButton13);
        root.getChildren().addAll(lblState2, toggleButton21, toggleButton22, toggleButton23);
        root.getChildren().addAll(lblState3, toggleButton31, toggleButton32, toggleButton33);
        //End create GUI

        //Start create ToggleButtons' event handlers.
        List<ToggleButton> toggleButtonList = new ArrayList();
        toggleButtonList.add(toggleButton11);
        toggleButtonList.add(toggleButton12);
        toggleButtonList.add(toggleButton13);
        toggleButtonList.add(toggleButton21);
        toggleButtonList.add(toggleButton22);
        toggleButtonList.add(toggleButton23);
        toggleButtonList.add(toggleButton31);
        toggleButtonList.add(toggleButton32);
        toggleButtonList.add(toggleButton33);

        for(ToggleButton tempToggleButton : toggleButtonList)
        {
            tempToggleButton.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
                if(tempToggleButton.isSelected())
                {
                    tempToggleButton.setText("*");
                }
                else
                {
                    tempToggleButton.setText("");
                }
            });
        }
        ////End create ToggleButtons' event handlers.



        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```